# Perl access elements in an array hash

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to access elements of an array of hashes.

This is a dump of my variable `$tst`

```
[
  { DESCRIPTION => "Default", ID => 0, NAME => "Default",  VERSION => "1.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 1, NAME => "Custom 1", VERSION => "1.1" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 2, NAME => "Custom 2", VERSION => "1.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 3, NAME => "Custom 3", VERSION => "6.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 4, NAME => "Custom 4", VERSION => "1.0" },
]
```

I am trying to access the values for the elements. For example if the ID is 4 then return the field `NAME`.

I tried printing all of the values for `ID` but it hasn't been working.

I used variations of the Perl code below from looking online

```
foreach ($tst) {
  print "$_->{'ID'}, \n";
}
```

And it gives the following error:

```
Not a HASH reference at file.pl line 22.
```

**Note**: line 22 is the `print` line from above.

Comment: Hi CircuitBOT, just a tip, when looking at the output of Data::Dumper, `[]` is for array references and `{}` is for hash references. You have an Array of Hashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first have to dereference the array of hash. So,

```
foreach (@$tst) {
    print $_->{ID}, "\n";
}
```

should print all the IDs.

Comment: Oh, wow. That worked perfectly, thank you. Could you possibly tell me or direct me to why `@$tst` worked?

Comment: Oh, nevermind I just saw that you said "array of hash". Thanks.

Comment: `@$tst` is the same as `@{ $tst }`, which is basically saying to look at (dereference) `$tst` as an array. This page might help. http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html

Answer (score 3):

The answer that you have accepted is correct, but your data structure is such that you can index the array by the ID value. That is to say `$tst->[$id]{ID} == $id` for all elements.

So, to print the `NAME` field for the `ID` 4 you can say

```
print $tst->[4]{NAME}, "\n";
```

and you will see

```
Custom 4
```

I hope this helps.